# can you use compound conditions in an if statement in pseudocode?

Tags: pseudocode

for example this simple program which tests if 3 numbers are in ascending order

```
if a1<a2 then
 if a2<a3 then 
    write "the numbers are in ascending order";
 else 
    write "the numbers are not in ascending order";
 endif
else 
 write "the numbers are not in ascending order;
endif
```

am i allowed to write it like this in pseudocode?

```
if (a1<a2 and a2<a3) 
  write "the numbers are in ascending order";
else 
  write "the numbers are not in ascending order";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As long as it's understandable and can easily be converted to real source code, it's fine as pseudocode.